# I get the error : Cannot read property 'then' of undefined when I run my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I get the error :

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

when I run my react project
The code is as follows

```
getQuestions = () => {
  quickService().then(question => {
    this.setState({
      questionBank: question
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: share`quickService` code

Comment: Can you share the code for your ‘quickService’ method?

Comment: Pls, show your `quickService` code. We can't reproduce your problem !!!

Answer (score 0):

You receive this error because your quickService() function doesn't return a promise, so you can't use .then() or .catch(). I think you should read about Promise in Javascript first.